# How do I convert spaces to underscores in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am writing a code to create files named after one column in an array, and then have all the common values of another column within it. I have successfully done this, but now **I would like to eliminate the white space in-between the file names and convert it into underscores. How do I do that?**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;

my @traitarray;
my $traitarray;
my $input ;
my %traithash ;
my $t_out ;
my $TRAIT;
my $SNPS;

open ($input, "gwas_catalog_v1.0-downloaded_2015-07-08") || die () ;

while(<$input>) {
    @traitarray = split (/\t/);
    $TRAIT = $traitarray[7];
    $SNPS = $traitarray[21];

        if (!exists $traithash {$TRAIT}) {
                open ($t_out, ">outputFiles/".$TRAIT.".txt");
                print ($t_out "$SNPS\n"); 
                $traithash {$TRAIT} = 1 ;
                push (@traitarray, $TRAIT) ;
        }
        else {
            print $t_out "$SNPS\n";
            }
}

foreach ($traitarray) {
    close "$TRAIT.txt";

}
```

I have tried looking for an answer but many of the questions either include something else as well, or how to go about this within the bash terminal, something I am not comfortable with yet, as I am still new to coding.

The file is  10947980 lines, and has 33 columns.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is there a particular line of your code that is problematic?  Can you define your goal a little more narrowly?

Comment: When my files are viewed, I would like them as "Prostate_Cancer" as opposed to how they appear now as "Prostate Cancer"  @JohnPirie

Answer (score 5):

You're presumably talking about the file you open with this

```
open ($t_out, ">outputFiles/".$TRAIT.".txt")
```

You can do that using the *transliterate* operator first `tr/ /_/` and your `open` call would be better written like this

```
my $outfile = "outputFiles/$TRAIT.txt";
$outfile =~ tr/ /_/;
open my $t_out, '>', $outfile or die qq{Unable to open "$outfile" for output: $!};
```

Comment: @Michaela: An I've just remembered you wanted some more commentary on my answer to your previous question. I'll take a look shortly!

Comment: it sounded like they might even want `tr/ /_/s`

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're referring to the value in the $TRAIT var which is then used as part of the new filename.

```
$TRAIT = $traitarray[7];
$TRAIT =~ s/\s+/_/g;
```